# If any value of $_POST is empty

Tags: php, arrays, post, input

So I know how to error check an empty post value with an if empty combination, however how can this be done if the post data is an array and it needs to be applied to each value?

Example:

```
foreach (array($_POST['post_values']) as $test) {print_r($test); echo'<br />';};
```

where

```
<input name="post_values[value_1]">
<input name="post_values[value_2]"> etc.
```

I need to be able to say that if a value is not posted to any of the inputs, then that particular input = zero without applying a default value to the inputs themselves.

Therefore if value_1 = 5 and value_2 = blank, the array will show as 5 and 0.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: You want to set to 0 all elements in the post_values array that are empty, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
foreach ($_POST['post_values'] as $key=>$test) {
    if($test==""){
        $_POST["post_values"][$key]=0;
    }
};
print_r($_POST['post_values']);
```

Comment: This method works like charm, thanks guys.  I'm an amateur by anyone's standards so the others may be correct also.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['post_values']); $i++){
    if (empty($_POST['post_values'][$i])){
        $_POST['post_values'][$i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following. inside your look you can check for value

$value = (trim($test) != "" ? $test : 0);

echo $value; // if $test is blank then it would be 0 else would get value of $test.